# \lowercase inside \url

Tags: macros, urls

Why is this snippet:

```
\newcommand{\Subject}{Skeleton}
\url{http://www.cheatsheet.jim.pm?subject=\lowercase{\Subject{}}}
```

rendered to this?

```
http://www.cheatsheet.jim.pm?subject=\lowercase{Skeleton}
```

and **not** the intended:

```
http://www.cheatsheet.jim.pm?subject=skeleton
```

Comment: I believe that `url` makes use of `verbatim`.

Comment: You are probably right @Sigur, but why does \Subject{} get expanded but not \lowercase?

Comment: `\lowercase` is not an expandable command.

Comment: @sigur: [`url`](http://ctan.org/pkg/url) proves a `\verb`-like command but does not use `verbatim` to do so.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`\lowercase` (and `{}`) are not expandable so you need to change the order of execution:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{url}

\newcommand{\Subject}{Skeleton}

\newcommand\lcURL[1]{%
  \edef\tmp{\lowercase{\noexpand\url{http://www.cheatsheet.jim.pm?subject=#1}}}%
  \tmp}

\begin{document}


\lcURL{\Subject}

\end{document}
```

If you need to remove space you need to use *expansion* only if you are not going to interfere with `\url`. Fortunately LaTeX has a built-in command to remove spaces via expansion:

```
\newcommand{\Subject}{Skeleton bones}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\lcURL[1]{%
  \edef\tmp{\lowercase{\noexpand\url{http://www.cheatsheet.jim.pm?subject=\zap@space#1 \@empty}}}%
  \tmp}
\makeatother
```

produces

```
http://www.cheatsheet.jim.pm?subject=skeletonbones
```

Comment: it works but I have no clue how, know I want to remove spaces from the \Subject with `\StrSubstitute{#1}{ }{}` but I cannot get it to compile and show properly, I tried putting inside the lcURL at different places as well as a function RemoveSpace that mimics the magic from lcURL but all in vain.
The most common error is _! Argument of \reserved@a has an extra }._

Comment: I don't think `\StrSubstitute` works via expansion so it will interfere with `\url`, see update.

Answer (score 3):

Just to see how one can use `\StrSubstitute` in this context:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{url,xstring}

\newcommand{\Subject}{Ske Le Ton}

\newcommand\lcURL[1]{%
  \begingroup
  \StrSubstitute{#1}{ }{}[\tmp]%
    \edef\tmp{%
      \lowercase{%
        \endgroup
        \noexpand\url{http://www.cheatsheet.jim.pm?subject=\tmp}%
      }%
    }%
  \tmp
}

\begin{document}

X\lcURL{\Subject}X

X\url{http://www.cheatsheet.jim.pm?subject=skeleton}X

\end{document}
```

With `\begingroup` and `\endgroup` we make sure that any definition of `\tmp` vanishes after usage.

[image]